# Does the limit exist ? and how to compute it?

Tags: limits, multivalued-functions

$$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,0)}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}$$

By direct substitution that's a 
( $ \frac{0}{0}$ ) undefined

so can I approach it by polar equation or by different paths ?

Mine was the polar form considering eqaution of circle is :

$$a(x-x_1)^2+b(y-y_1)^2$$

Comment: Mayar: the editor made the assumption that the entire demominator is under the square root site.  What you wrote suggests you could have also meant the denominator to be $\sqrt{(x-1)^2} + y^2$.  Can you please either confirm the edit, or else the variation I've just mentioned.  Your original post was ambiguous.

Comment: It is as the editor did the whole denomirator under the root

Comment: HINT wlog we can have the limit $ \dfrac{x}{r}= \cos \theta$ after translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different paths are useful in this exercise, easy to choose and compute.

If $x=1$ you get $0.$

If $x>1$ and $y=0,$ the result is $1.$

This is enough to conclude that the limite does not exist.

Comment: For the second path maybe $x>1$ or $x< 1$ is more indicated and the limit is $\pm 1$. For that reason I’ve suggested a change of variables, it is not necessary but it is recommended in order to avoid such kind of mistakes. In general indeed it is always better to refer to limit at the origin or at $\infty$. We are not forced to fo that explicitly but it is better at lest check the result in that way.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear, but you line "If $x>0$ and $y=0,$ the result is $1$" is not correct.

Comment: Right, I am editing now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=u+1, \, v=y$ with $(u,v)\to (0,0)$ then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,0)}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(u,v)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$$

and since by polar coordinates $\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=\cos \theta$ we can conclude that the limit doesn't exist, indeed

- $u=0 \implies \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=0$
- $u=v \implies \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2}2$

Answer (score 1):

Put

$$x=1+r\cos(t)$$
and

$$y=r\sin(t)$$

the function becomes

$$\frac{r\cos(t)}{r}=\cos(t)$$

the limit depends on the angle $t$, so
The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: If applied the different path method it brings a not existing limit , could you please show me another workout using the different paths method in proving the limit's existence

Comment: The different paths method serves to prove non-existence. To prove the existence, a different method is needed.

Comment: So how it doesnot exist by the polar coordinates ? after$$cos(t)$$

Comment: $\cos(t)$ is not a constant, gets different values ...

Comment: oooh okay its not an existing limit bec yes because it doen't equal one constant value , yes I get it now , thank you

Comment: @Mayar Yes. the result should not depend on the direction.